# Convert Expression Tree to String and vice versa for WCF

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, serialization, expression-trees

I want to **Convert Expression Tree to String and Visa versa** for using in WCF client and server query expression

convert expression tree to string for send to server and convert string to expression tree in server so need this converter

seems [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) is good library for this purpose so if yes please show me an example for this converting if no please any one show me a way for solve this problem

i dont know how System.Linq.Dynamic works for this goal (example please)

******* of course i want to use  [Serialize.Linq](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Serialize.Linq/) to convert Expression tree to serializable object but this library does not work for me because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435468/serialize-linq-does-not-work-in-wcf-proxy-layer)

Comment: Why do you think simply using another approach to serialization will solve the problem? It seems to me the problem is with proxies to `Expression`s, not with Serialize.Linq.

Comment: Are you any suggestion ? I like to use Serialize.Linq but I could not , WCF Proxy generate auto classess and dont use added reference Serialize.Linq assembly classes , Can you help me for using Serialize.Linq ?